# Apps Script External Stylesheet

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I am trying to use a single HTML stylesheet that I've created between multiple apps script web app projects.  I have the HTML stylesheet hosted on an external site but cannot figure out the code to include that external stylesheet into my apps script projects.

I've currently got it working with the following code in my Index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<?!= include('stylesheet') ?>
```

The include function calls:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
```

And my stylesheet is a separate HTML file in my Apps Script.

This all works well, but I'd like to have a central repository elsewhere (I've read that I cannot link to an Apps Script file in another project) for my stylesheet so that whatever changes I make will update to all of my Apps Script projects automatically.

To do this, I've uploaded my stylesheet.html to a website and have taken the link that points to the file (i.e. http://www.test.com/stylesheet.html) and tried to do the following without success:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.test.com/stylesheet.html">
```

I've placed this in the head element of my Index.html file, and I also tried it above the head element.  Neither worked.

I've also tried to just use the include function that worked as mentioned above and modify my stylesheet.html to be blank except for:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.test.com/stylesheet.html">
```

None of this seems to work, wondering if anyone else has any thoughts on how this might be possible.

Comment: Welcome to [so] Show what you tried as well a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Rubén, I've made some edits to reflect your comments.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. By the way,  you might have to use .css instead of .html as the file extension and remove any html tag from your stylesheet file.

Comment: Thank you Rubén.  I changed the filename to .css and hosted the file on Google Drive per the instructions found here (https://hwpi.harvard.edu/assetslibrary/host-css-or-js-file-google-drive) and using the link generated from the Havard page I can link to my CSS stylesheet using <link rel="stylesheet" href="google_drive_link_goes_here">.  This now works perfectly.  Thank you for your help and patience as I learned this and how to use stackoverflow for the first time.

Comment: Please post the solution that work for you as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Host CSS file in Google Drive

Create a `.css` stylesheet file and host it on Google Drive.
Change the uploaded file permissions to publish it on the Web.

Now copy the published file ID and use it to build the following URL:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILE-ID-GOES-HERE
```

Now include the generated URL to your HTML page using the `<link/>` tag in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="google_drive_link_goes_here">
```

### Reference

[Host CSS or JS file on Google Drive](https://hwpi.harvard.edu/assetslibrary/host-css-or-js-file-google-drive)